# No results even by using EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I don't undersand why MySQL returns "MySQL did not produce a record" whereas I use EXISTS (I willingly chose a subquery which doesn't produce records) :

```
SELECT  page_ID
    FROM ranks_update
    WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ranks_update
    WHERE ranking_ID = 3
        AND current_rank = 1
        AND rating_time < '2012-08-05 02:57:59'
        AND rating_time >= '2012-08-05 00:00:00'  
    GROUP BY page_ID
);
```

By definition EXISTS allows to get a result from a query which doesn't return any records. Until now I've always got NULL in such case.

Comment: What does the subquery return?

Comment: I willingly chose a subquery which doesn't produce records..

Comment: EXISTS(aaa) yields a boolean value, in your case "False". You can replace the `WHERE EXISTS (...)` by `WHERE (1 = 0)` and get the same result. BTW: the subquery is uncorrelated to the main query. Is this your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning that message because no records match.  NULL is a value for a column.  It is quite different from an empty return set.

If you have an aggregate function, then the empty set returns a NULL.  So the following would return a NULL value:

```
select max(Page_ID)
```

and this would return 0:

```
select count(Page_ID)
```

Comment: Ok, so if my final purpose is to do a test on the value of page_iD like "SELECT IF( page_ID > 10, 1 ,'0 ).. WHERE EXISTS ..", I'm always forced to use MAX : "SELECT IF( MAX(page_ID) > 10, 1 ,'0 ).. WHERE EXISTS .." ?

Comment: Yes, or COUNT().  Or, you can use a really complicated query, but the aggregation is the easiest way.